# Unable to find Google Analytics API hostnames

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-java-client

On my company box, machines has no internet access. I've to create a firewall rule in order allow machines access for specific host.

I need pull data from Google analytic API, but it is not accessible as well. I've to add google analytics api hostnames, but unfortunately not able to find list anywhere on internet. Also I've installed `Fiddler` - traffic sniffer and was trying to find out hosts by intercepting a packets, but seems like nothing was captured.

Could you please help me to find out Google Analytics API host lists?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not just the Google Analytics API host your going to need to be able to access the Autentication server as well.

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/

The Google Analytics core reporting api url is:

> https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga

The Google Analytics  Managment API url is:

> https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management

I am not sure if that is going to help you get it to work but it should answer your question.